# FieldValue.arrayUnion() creates a null value in array at very first update/set flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am facing issue of an empty value/object being created at the very first post to firebase when i update array using FieldValue.arrayUnion().

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> commentsList = [];
Future<void> postComment (String postId, String comment, String commentBy) async{
commentsList.add({
    'comment' : comment,
    'commentBy' : commentBy
  });
  
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').doc(postId).collection('comments').doc(postId).update({
  'comments' : FieldValue.arrayUnion(commentsList)
});
```

}

Now when i call this function to post data then data is created successfully on firebase but it also has a null value at the very first time data is created in collection.

These are the screenshots:

Before function execution:

[image: firebase screenshot 1]

After function execution:

[image: firebase screenshot 2]

I also tried to update data with .set() method and adding SetOptions(merge : true). Data is being created and merging successfully but again with a null element being created as shown in screenshots above.

Anyone knows what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Sorry about this question. It was a logical error at my side. The problem was that i was creating null values for the comments array while mapping querySnapshot data to my comments list. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution. Could you also post it as the answer so the community would benefit from it?

Answer (score 0):

It was a logical error. The problem was that I was creating `null` values for the `comments` array while mapping `querySnapshot` data to my comments list.